# Como inserir quantidade estipulada do mesmo registro no banco com id diferente no LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um formulário que já cria um registro por vez no banco. Gostaria de informar neste mesmo formulário através de um **campo quantidade** ($request->quant) onde posso informar a quantidade a ser criada ou duplicada desse mesmo registro com id diferente.

Seguue o código do meu Controller:

```
public function criarRegistro(Request $request)
{


    $this->validate($request,[
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'card_details' => 'required',
        'card_image' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,svg',
        'impuls' => 'required',
    ]);



    if($request->hasFile('card_image')){
        $image = $request->file('card_image');
        $imageName = time().'.jpg';
        $location = 'assets/images/cardimage/'.$imageName;
        Image::make($image)->save($location);
        $name = $imageName;
    }else{
        $name = '';
        $impuls = '';

    }

    $cat = cardsubcategory::find($request->category_id );


    // AQUI ONDE ESTOU TENTANDO FAZER A MULTIPLICAÇÃO DO MESMO REGISTRO 
     $numero = $request->quant * $cat;




    card::create([
       'sub_category_id' => $request->category_id,
       'card_details' => $request->card_details,
       'card_image' => $name,
       'category_id' => $cat->id,
       'status' => 1,
       'tipo' => 1,
       'impuls' => $request->impuls,
    ]);


    return back()->with('success', 'Criado com Sucesso');
}
```

Comment: Você tá querendo duplicar o cardsubcategory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar o create em um laço `for` para resolver esse problema

```
public function criarRegistro(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'card_details' => 'required',
        'card_image' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,svg',
        'impuls' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('card_image')){
        $image = $request->file('card_image');
        $imageName = time().'.jpg';
        $location = 'assets/images/cardimage/'.$imageName;
        Image::make($image)->save($location);
        $name = $imageName;
    }else{
        $name = '';
        $impuls = '';
    }

    //Laço para percorrer a quantidade definida em $request->quant
    for ($i = 0; $i < $request->quant; $i++) {
        card::create([
           'sub_category_id' => $request->category_id,
           'card_details' => $request->card_details,
           'card_image' => $name,
           'category_id' => $request->category_id,
           'status' => 1,
           'tipo' => 1,
           'impuls' => $request->impuls,
        ]);
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Criado com Sucesso');
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, valeu demais. Resolveu!